# React-Native image resize mode producing strange artifacts

Tags: react-native

I am struggling to create a flatlist with React Native which works as an image grid.

Here's a list of what I am aiming to do:

- create a scrollable window
- of square panels in a grid layout
- there should be two columns of squares
- each square panel contains a photo
- the photo should be fully contained within the square (the whole photo should be visible not cropped)
- if there are an odd number of photos in the camera roll, the final grid square should just be blank

This is what my emulator is producing:

[image: simulator]

It is not as I would expect as some strange artifact is occurring at the top and bottom of each image.

To try and "debug" it, I have been playing around with bold colors. The final result will not have these strange red lines or border radius. This is just to help me visualize what is going on.

Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening?

*I tried both "center" and "contain" options for the images, but neither appeared to work. Both produced the same results with this artifacting. Why does it happen?*

My code is also provided, here:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";

const flatListNumberOfColumns = 2;

function ImageGridView(props) {
  const flatListData = [
    { key: 1, name: "name1" },
    { key: 2, name: "name2" },
    { key: 3, name: "name3" },
    { key: 4, name: "name4" },
    { key: 5, name: "name5" },
    { key: 6, name: "name6" },
    { key: 7, name: "name7" },
    { key: 8, name: "name8" },
    { key: 9, name: "name9" },
  ];

  const formatData = (data, numColumns) => {
    const numberOfFullRows = Math.floor(data.length / numColumns);
    let numberOfRemainderElements = data.length - numberOfFullRows * numColumns;

    if (numberOfRemainderElements > 0) {
      while (numberOfRemainderElements !== numColumns) {
        data.push({ key: `blank-${numberOfRemainderElements}`, empty: true });
        numberOfRemainderElements += 1;
      }
    }

    return data;
  };

  const flatListRenderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    if (item.empty === true) {
      return (
        <View
          style={styles.flatListItem} // just render an empty panel
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.flatListItem}>
        <Image
          style={styles.photo}
          source={require("../assets/images/avatar3-solid.png")}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <FlatList
        data={formatData(flatListData, flatListNumberOfColumns)}
        renderItem={flatListRenderItem}
        numColumns={flatListNumberOfColumns}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 40, // TODO: remove this and fix properly
  },
  photo: {
    resizeMode: "contain",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1,
    maxHeight: "100%",
    maxWidth: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    borderColor: "red",
    borderWidth: 10,
    borderRadius: 66,
  },
  flatListItem: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    margin: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
});

export default ImageGridView;
```

Here is the image I am using as the test Avatar.

[image: avatar]

Answer (score 0):

When you set border width in image with "resizeMode: 'contain'"

It will try to fit in the borders. When you remove border settings, it will be normal.

So what can you do?

You can add a view and put the image in it. And you can give border to that view. If image doesnt fit inside of the view you can set 'overflow: hidden'.

The main question is How do you want it to look?

If you added your borders to debug it. I've used your code. Removed borders and the result is;

[image]